Can an Excel Filter function base its include on a whole row?
I have a Table from which I pull a list of unique values, then I want to pull all their keys and merge them using textjoin. But the Filter function the criteria to be compared against a single value, while I want the criteria to look for a whole row.
In normal circumstances I would just stick with a single value and let it drag town with a table, but in this case the source is a Unique function so it can't be a table.




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Item
Key


Item
Key


2
foo
apple


foo
apple,orange


3
bar
apple


bar
apple,orange


4
foo
orange






5
bar
orange






6
bar
apple







Right now I have:

A1:B6 is a Table called Table1
For the items:
=UNIQUE(A1:A)


For the keys results column, starting from Row 2:
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=E2))
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=E3))
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=E4))
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=E5))
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=E6))



But the data is dynamic so I can't keep doing D5, D6, etc. and also I don't want to just drag down over unused cells because it slows down the file.
So what I'm looking for is something like =TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=E:E)) plus only for non empty D cells, so the result will be without having to put formulas in E3, E4, etc.
Is it possible?
Also, what if there are multiple keys i.e. for Row it's =TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(Table2[Key1] & " - " & Table2[Key2], Table1[Item]=E2))?




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Item
Key
Key2

Item
Key


2
foo
apple
grapes

foo
apple - grapes,orange - apple


3
bar
apple
plum

bar
apple - plum,orange - test


4
foo
orange
apple





5
bar
orange
test





6
bar
apple
plum






Note that I have a similar Google Sheets specific question on Web Applications.

Here are alternatives that don't rely on 365 (which users can use this):

VBA UDF Macro
Power Query

1. VBA UDF Macro:

Benefit - loads in a second even if the source data has thousands of rows
Caveat - requires enabling macros and all changes need to be done purely in code

Instructions:

Paste the following code into a VBA editor module
Use it in the cell in which you want the output via either:

1 range for everything, e.g. =ConcatenateKeysForItems(Table1[#All]) or =ConcatenateKeysForItems(a1:c6)
1 range for items and just 1 range for keys, e.g. =ConcatenateKeysForItems(Table1[[#All],[Item]], Table1[[#All],[Key]]) or =ConcatenateKeysForItems(a1:a6, b1:b6)
1 range for items, 1 range for key1, and 1 range for key2, e.g. =ConcatenateKeysForItems(Table1[[#All],[Item]],Table1[[#All],[Key]],Table1[[#All],[Key2]]) or =ConcatenateKeysForItems(a1:a6, b1:b6, c1:c6)


Optional

Modify the first lines to change the separators and exclusions
If you want it to automatically update every time the source data is updated (like a native formula), then there's another code below which you can paste into the VBA editor's ThisWorkbook



Function ConcatenateKeysForItems(rng As Range, Optional rngKey1 As Range = Nothing, Optional rngKey2 As Range = Nothing) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, disallowedKeys As Variant, sepInternal As String, sepExternal As String
    sepInternal = " - "
    sepExternal = ","
    disallowedKeys = Array("0", "-1")
    Set ws = rng.Worksheet
    
    If UBound(disallowedKeys) = -1 Then
        disallowedKeys = Array("")
    End If
    If rngKey1 Is Nothing And rngKey2 Is Nothing And rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        ' Since there's only one column, simply return the unique items
        ConcatenateKeysForItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(rng.Columns(1))
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim item As Variant, keyValue As Variant, value2 As Variant
    Dim combinedValue As String
    Dim row As Range
    Dim colCount As Long
    colCount = rng.Columns.Count
    
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        item = row.Cells(1, 1).Value
        If Not dict.Exists(item) Then
            dict.Add item, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        
        If Not rngKey1 Is Nothing Then
            keyValue = rngKey1.Cells(row.row - rng.row + 1, 1).Value
        Else
            keyValue = row.Cells(1, 2).Value ' Get keyValue from second column if rngKey1 is Nothing
        End If
      
        ' Determine value2 and create combinedValue
        If Not rngKey2 Is Nothing Or (colCount > 2 And rngKey1 Is Nothing) Then
            If Not rngKey2 Is Nothing Then
                value2 = rngKey2.Cells(row.row - rng.row + 1, 1).Value
            Else
                ' Use the third column for value2 only if rngKey1 is Nothing and rng has more than 2 columns
                value2 = row.Cells(1, 3).Value
            End If
            combinedValue = keyValue & sepInternal & value2
            
            If Not dict(item).Exists(combinedValue) Then
                dict(item).Add combinedValue, Array(keyValue, value2, combinedValue)
            End If
        Else
            ' If rngKey2 is Nothing and colCount <= 2, or rngKey1 is not nothing but colCount <= 2
            If Not dict(item).Exists(keyValue) Then
                dict(item).Add keyValue, Array(keyValue, "", "")
            End If
        End If
    Next row
    
    ' Prepare the output array based on the conditions
    Dim output() As Variant
    Dim outputCols As Long
    If Not rngKey2 Is Nothing Or (colCount > 2 And rngKey1 Is Nothing) Then
        outputCols = 4 ' Item, Keys, Values, Key-Value Combinations
    Else
        outputCols = 2 ' Item, Keys
    End If
    ReDim output(1 To dict.Count, 1 To outputCols)
    
    Dim k As Long: k = 1
    For Each item In dict.Keys
        Dim allKeys As String: allKeys = ""
        Dim allValues As String: allValues = ""
        Dim allCombinations As String: allCombinations = ""
        Dim disallowedPrevent As Boolean
        For Each keyValue In dict(item).Keys
            Dim details As Variant
            details = dict(item)(keyValue)
            ' If first entry or not disallowed
            If allKeys = "" Or IsError(Application.Match(details(0) & "", disallowedKeys, 0)) Then
                disallowedPrevent = False
                ' If not first entry or not disallowed
                If allKeys <> "" And Not IsError(Application.Match(allKeys, disallowedKeys, 0)) Then
                    disallowedPrevent = True
                End If
                allKeys = IIf(disallowedPrevent, "", allKeys & IIf(allKeys = "", "", sepExternal)) & details(0)
                If outputCols = 4 Then
                    allValues = IIf(disallowedPrevent, "", allValues & IIf(allValues = "", "", sepExternal)) & details(1)
                    allCombinations = IIf(disallowedPrevent, "", allCombinations & IIf(allCombinations = "", "", sepExternal)) & details(2)
                End If
            End If
        Next keyValue
        output(k, 1) = item  ' Item names
        output(k, 2) = allKeys  ' Keys
        If outputCols = 4 Then
            output(k, 3) = allValues ' Values (for ranges with more than 2 columns or when rngKey2 is specified)
            output(k, 4) = allCombinations ' Key-Value Combinations
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next item
    
    ConcatenateKeysForItems = output
End Function

Use this to sync the output to the input - change the first line to define the input (e.g. Table1 in Sheet1) and output (e.g. E7):
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Const source_rg As String = "Table1", source_sh As String = "Sheet1", target_cell As String = "E7"
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next ' In case there's no such table
    Set tbl = Sh.ListObjects(source_rg)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn back on regular error handling
    
    ' Check if the changed range intersects with the table
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.Range) Is Nothing Then
            ' If change is within Table1, recalculate your specific cell
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(source_sh).Range(target_cell).Calculate
        End If
    End If
End Sub

2. Power Query

Benefit - simpler and doesn't require enabling macros
Caveat - crashes Excel when the source data has many rows (thousands of lines are already overkill)

Instructions:

Choose your original table and Data=>From Table/Range (under Get & Transform Data)
Right click the last step and choose Insert Step After
Replace the formula on top with (and rename Previous Step Name):

If you have just 1 Key column, then: = Table.Group(#"Previous Step Name", {"Item"}, {{"CombinedKeys", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Transform(Table.Column(_, "Key"), Text.From)), ","), type text}})
If you have multiple Key columns, then: = Table.Group(#"Previous Step Name", {"Item"}, {{"CombinedKeys", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(_), each Text.From([Key1]) & " - " & Text.From([Key2]))), ","), type text}})


Exit Power Query and choose Keep

P.S.
If you want to filter out certain keys, like "0" and "-1", here's how:
= Table.Group(#"Previous Step Name", {"Item"}, {{"CombinedKeys", each Text.Combine(
    let
        currentRecords = Table.ToRecords(_),
        nonZeroNonNegativeOneRecords = List.Select(currentRecords, each Text.From([Key1]) <> "0" and Text.From([Key1]) <> "-1"),
        zeroOrNegativeOneRecords = List.Select(currentRecords, each Text.From([Key1]) = "0" or Text.From([Key1]) = "-1"),
        validZeroOrNegativeOneRecords = List.Select(zeroOrNegativeOneRecords, each List.IsEmpty(List.Select(nonZeroNonNegativeOneRecords, (nr) => nr[Item] = _[Item]))),
        combinedRecords = List.Combine({nonZeroNonNegativeOneRecords, validZeroOrNegativeOneRecords}),
        combinedTexts = List.Distinct(List.Transform(combinedRecords, each Text.From([Key1]) & " - " & [Key2]))
    in
        combinedTexts, ","), type text}})


I don't think your caveat that PowerQuery will crash Excel is valid - we use PQ all the time to pull in thousands and tens of thousands of rows of data, join tables together etc with no real issues.

First of all, I meant hundreds of thousands of rows. Secondly, this specific Table.Group gets crashed for me while the VBA doesn't.

Here is what you can do using BYROW() which applies a custom LAMBDA() calculations to each row in the array of x to check if each value in x is equal to Table1[Item] to return a delimited list one output per row with respective Table1[Key].


=BYROW(D1#,LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(Table1[Key],Table1[Item]=x,","))))


Or, using MAP()
=VSTACK(",",DROP(MAP(D1#,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(x=Table1[Item],Table1[Key],"")))),1))


This is only an alternative, not needed as BYROW() should do, what you are trying to achieve, here is using MAP() function:
=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(D:D<>"")),
     VSTACK(", ",MAP(D2:INDEX(D:D,_LastRow), LAMBDA(x,
     TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(Table1[Item]=x,Table1[Key],""))))))



Nice! But BYROW(), LAMBDA(), VSTACK() and MAP() seem to be Office 365 exclusive functions. Is there a regular Office alternative?

@LWC what is your version ? Excel 2021?

Yes, that's the one

@LWC you will certainly need a helper/intermediate columns.

Also note that using TEXTJOIN() for the whole array is not suggestive, let say you have a data around 20K then at certain point the TEXTJOIN() function will return #VALUE! error, as TEXTJOIN() function has character limitations if the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), suggestive will be to use what you are using presently or use Power Query

What can be the helper/intermediate column (hopefully not in plural)? And how can they be dynamic to suit any number of rows?

@LWC no sorry it won't work here, as it will referencing the whole column. Even if i come up with some formulas, it will be pretty slow and not recommended. I will suggest you to use Power Query more flexible than anything

Since I can't test without 365, will it also work in the newly added case of multiple keys?

That is a different question, which doesn't relates with your original question and the answer posted earlier was related to that, new question should be raised as a new post.

If I do that, the kind hearts here are likely to close it since it's too similar, I'm sorry for remembering just later. Your answer is still amazing. Hope you'll consider modifying anyway.

No those kind hearts wont close, because first they will read the edits and see, why it has been posted twice, secondly, I am not going to change my answer, because its a complete different question which was not mentioned 10 hrs back. Lot of time was there
